# Automatically Upgrading Between Major VirtualBox Versions on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have VirtuaBox installed on Ubuntu 18.04. Upgrading to a minor version (ex. VirtualBox 6.1.2 to VirtualBox 6.1.3) is as easy as running a

`sudo apt-get update`

command. However, when a major revision is released (ex. VirtualBox 6.0 to VirtualBox 6.1), I have to manually uninstall the old version of VirtualBox and install the new one since the package names are different (ex. `virtualbox-6.0`, `virtualbox-6.1`, etc.).

The next time there's a major version release (ex. VirtualBox 6.2), I'd like the upgrade to happen automatically. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance to the community for their help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is entirely normal. VMware Workstation uninstalls the old version prior to a major release. Other software (not virtualizing software) also does this. You must update the way the vendor says you must (for any software)

Comment: I was speaking about VirtualBox, not VMWare, but I concede the same logic applies. Installing the new VirtualBox does uninstall the old one first, but I would still like to upgrade to new VirtualBox versions automatically, not manually. You're suggesting that's not possible?

Comment: I understand but if any given vendor says uninstall first, you must. I was just giving you examples. Some application versions cannot upgrade in place.

Comment: That's weird. Why would a vendor decide not to do that? Why not just have a single package called "virtualbox" that always contains the latest version?

Comment: I have seen a number of vendors require uninstall prior to update. Not all the time, not unless necessary, but enough to call it reasonably common

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's no built-in automated way to update VirtualBox for more than maintenance/build/revision releases. For those who might be interested, I wrote a Bash script that checks for a new major or minor release in the Ubuntu repository and then installs it if it exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current virtualbox verion and parse out the major and minor numbers
curVersion=$(vboxmanage --version)
IFS='.' read -ra curVersionArray <<< "$curVersion"
majorNum=${curVersionArray[0]}
minorNum=${curVersionArray[1]}

# Get the next major and minor numbers
majorNextNum=$((majorNum + 1))
minorNextNum=$((minorNum + 1))

# Check to see if the next minor version exists
minorNext=virtualbox-$majorNum.$minorNextNum
testCache=$(sudo apt-cache search $minorNext)
if [ ! -z "$testCache" ]; then 
    echo $minorNext " found! Installing...";
    sudo apt-get -y install $minorNext
else 
    echo $minorNext " does not yet exist"; 
fi

# Check to see if the next major version exists
majorNext=virtualbox-$majorNextNum.0
testCache=$(sudo apt-cache search $majorNext)
if [ ! -z "$testCache" ]; then 
    echo $majorNext " found! Installing...";
    sudo apt-get -y install $majorNext 
else 
    echo $majorNext " does not yet exist"; 
fi
```

Comment: Given there is no way (as I noted), you might consider acknowledging my answer.